# Vakil's Exercise 1.3.K (b): Natural ring structure of a tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

This problem is taken from Vakil's Foundations of Algebraic Geometry (Exercise 1.3.K. (b)):

> **Problem**: If $\varphi: A \to B$ and $\psi: A \to C$ are two morphisms of rings, show that $B \otimes_A C$ has a natural structure of a ring.

In his notes, Vakil even gives us the multiplication: $$(b_1 \otimes c_1) (b_2 \otimes c_2) := (b_1 b_2) \otimes (c_1 c_2).$$

Now I do not understand why we need the maps in the first place. I know that $B$ and $C$ can obtain an $A$-module structure via $\varphi$ resp. $\psi$, so the notion $B \otimes_A C$ makes sense. However, why can we not just take arbitrary rings $B$ and $C$. As I tried to go through all ring axioms with the multiplication above, it seems like every axiom is still correct.

Could you let me know what I am missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, you don't need the maps $A \to B$ and $A \to C$. But the ring you get will (in general) not be the same: it will be $B \otimes_{\mathbb Z} C$, associated to the (canonical) maps $\mathbb Z \to B$, $\mathbb Z \to C$.

Comment: In your case, we have $A = \mathbb{Z}$. This means that $\mathbb{Z} \to B$ and $\mathbb{Z} \to C$ (since $\mathbb{Z}$ is the initial object in the category of groups and therefore $B \otimes_\mathbb{Z} C$ would be uniquely determined. 

What you are trying to say now is that, for an arbitrary ring $A$, the tensor product $B \otimes_A C$, in general, depends on the scalar multiplication of $B$ and $C$ which means it depends on the maps $A \to B$ and $A \to C$. Is that correct?

Comment: That is right. What I wanted to say is that the ring $B \otimes_A C$ depends on the algebra $A$. But as you say, it certainly depends on the maps $A\to B, C$ as well.